# How to print proxy and add it to the server?

Tags: bash, jenkins, cloudbees

I'm trying to ssh into the server. I added my credential in Jenkins and called it from Jenkins. I think I might be getting a proxy error and I don't know how to print proxy in Jenkins. `print $http_proxy` didn't work.

```
withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: "7xxxxx-xxx-xxx", keyFileVariable: 'key_file')]) {
    echo "passed" // printed passed
    ssh -i ${key_file} -tt -vvv -o LogLevel=DEBUG3 centos@xxxx.net // stuck here.
    echo "passing?" // not printing any yet.
```

I'm using Cloudbees Jenkins.

printed output is...

```
ssh -i **** -tt -vvv -o LogLevel=DEBUG3 
...
08:56:36  debug3: send packet: type 30
08:56:36  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
08:56:36  debug3: receive packet: type 31
08:56:36  debug1: Server host key:
```

I think the first thing I can is to start to find a proxy. I've been working on this for hours but couldn't figure it out. :(